# alternate to FlatList in react native

Tags: reactjs, mobile, react-native, react-android

How to use FlatList feature in older react native versions ,my react native version is 0.41.2. Please suggest.I want to use flatlist in the collapsible sets to render large data.

Answer (score 1):

Trust me, there is no way that you can use FlatList component without using RN version 0.43 and newer. The only way that you can do is upgrade your RN version.

Comment: So could you please guide me impacts of upgrading to latest one with steps .

Comment: You can easily follow the steps from here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use RecyclerListView instead. It is faster than FlatList and battle tested at Flipkart. Works 0.30+

Link: https://github.com/Flipkart/ReactEssentials

You can read more about it here: https://medium.com/@naqvitalha/recyclerlistview-high-performance-listview-for-react-native-and-web-e368d6f0d7ef

Comment: with dynamic item height dont work well, even slower than flatlist.

Comment: doesn't work on dynamic height. for flatlist like facebook posts, this is useless

Comment: If you set forceNonDeterministicRendering to true it will treat given dimensions as estimates and will work with dynamic heights. Flipkart's most lists are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

FlatList was released on 0.44. For previously versions you should use ListView. 
Simple example from the official docs:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html

Comment: yes I'm using but have some performance issue, that's way i'm asking for FlatList

Comment: Listview do not support multiple columns display which Flatlist do.

Comment: For versions below 0.44 the option for rendering lists is ListView, but it doesn’t mean that it has all features that FlatList does. If you need FlatList features, you should update your RN version and use it

Answer (score 0):

use react-native-optimized-flatlist for stable and faster response.

```
npm i react-native-optimized-flatlist
```